# Fourier transform of $\cos(kx)$ using the formula given.

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I want to find the Fourier transform of $$ f(x) = \cos (kx)$$
using the Fourier transformation formula $$f(k)={1\over  \sqrt{2\pi}}\int _{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{ikx}dk$$

How can I do that?

Comment: do you know the delta distribution?

Comment: yes i know but i am confused ! how should i use it or replace it !

Comment: use $cos(kx)=\Im(e^{ikx})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tired mentioned, a delta function, $\delta(x)$, is a distribution that satisfies
$$\int _{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x-a)f(x)=f(a)$$
Indeed the Fourier transform of the function $g(x)=1$ is a [delta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html).So we should Write 
$$\delta(\omega)={1\over  \sqrt{2\pi}}\int _{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\omega x}dx$$
$$\mathcal{F}[f(x)](\omega)={1\over  \sqrt{2\pi}}\int _{-\infty}^\infty \cos (kx)\,e^{i\omega x}dx={1\over  \sqrt{2\pi}}\int _{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx}}{2}\right) e^{i\omega x}dx$$
we have
$$\mathcal{F}[f(x)](\omega)={1\over  2\sqrt{2\pi}}\int _{-\infty}^\infty \left(e^{ix(\omega +k)}+e^{ix(\omega -k)}\right) dx$$
$$\mathcal{F}[f(x)](\omega)={1\over  2}\delta(\omega+k)+\frac 12\delta(\omega-k)$$

Comment: how do you define $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikx} e^{i \omega x} dx$ ? I think you should better use inverse Fourier transforms of $\delta$ (that is well-defined whenever $\delta$ is well-defined : $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(\omega-a) e^{i \omega x} d\omega = e^{i ax}$) @AtiqurRahman

Comment: so assuming the Fourier inversion theorem works for (tempered) distributions, we have $\mathcal{F}^{-1}[\delta(\omega-k)+\delta(\omega+k)] = 2 \cos(kx) \implies \mathcal{F}[\cos(kx)] = \frac{\delta(\omega-k)+\delta(\omega+k)}{2}$

Comment: Yes .It is nice